# Unable to connect to MySQL DB on AWS

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2

we have MySQL server on AWS. I can connect to MySQL from tableau Desktop.But, While i am trying to connect from Tableau Server i am unable to connect. and getting this error " Unable to connect to the ODBC Data Source. Check that the necessary drivers are installed and that the connection properties are valid. [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aws-rds-mysql-1.cvemwozffwfo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060) Unable to connect to the server "aws-rds-mysql-1.cvemwozffwfo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database." SO, can someone help to solve this issue. Which driver to be installed to connect to MySQL on AWS?

Comment: Check the security group that's applied to the RDS instance.

Comment: Also check 3306 port. it should be opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495448/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-aws-rds

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are trying to connect, but as the comments states:

1. Check the Security Group
2. Check port 3306 (`telnet <RDSendpoint> 3306`)
3. `mysql -h <RDS Endpoint> -u <Username> -p <dbname>`

That's how I connect to my RDS instance